# Linear transformation problem -solution check ; proving general results in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Let $U,V,W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $T:U\rightarrow V, S:V\rightarrow W$ be linear transformations.

(i) Prove that $ker(T)\subseteq ker(ST)$ and deduce that $rank(T)\ge rank (ST)$

(ii) If $S$ is 1-1 prove that $ker(ST)\subseteq ker(T)$ and that $rank(ST)=rank(T)$

(iii) Suppose $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ is a basis for $U$, $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis for $V$ and that $T$ is defined by $T(u_1)=v_1+v_2, T(u_2)=2v_1+v_2, T(u_3)=v_1-v_2$. Prove that $T$ maps $U$ onto the whole of $V$ but that $T$ is not 1-1.

My solution:

(i) $Ker(ST)=\{u|S(T(u))=0\}$.  If $S$ is 1-1 then $Ker (ST)=Ker(T)$. But if $S$ is not 1-1 then for some $v$ we have $S(v)=0$, with $v\ne 0$. We can have $v=T(u)$ and so $ST(u)=0$ with $T(u)\ne 0$. As such $Ker(T)\subseteq Ker(ST)$. Rank nullity theorem says that $rank(T)=n-null(T)\ge n-null(ST)$ by the previous line. As such $rank(ST)\ge rank(T)$ as claimed.

(ii) If $S$ is 1-1 then $S(a)=S(b)\Rightarrow a=b$. $Ker(ST)=\{u|ST(u)=0\}$.But since $S$ is 1-1 and $S(0)=0$ we have $T(u)=0$. As such $Ker(ST)=\{0\}\subseteq Ker(T)$, as $T$ may not be 1-1. so $rank(T)\le rank(ST)$. But we proved earlier the opposite result and combining these gives $rank(ST)=rank(T)$.

(iii) I am not confident about this solution as it doesn't use $T(v_2) $ anywhere. $T(u_1+u_3)=2v_1$ and also $T(u_1-u_3)=2v_2$. So we have scalars $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha T(u_1+u_3)+\beta T(u_1-u_3)=\alpha v_1+\beta v_2$ which is the condition for spanning $V$. I don't know how to show it is not 1-1 though.

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 3):

(i) There is no need to consider $S$ is injective separately. If $Tv=0$, then $ST(v)=S(T(v))=S(0)=0$, hence $Ker(T) \subseteq Ker(ST)$. The inequality sign in the conclusion of part $(i)$ is written wrongly.

(ii) $Ker(ST)=\{0\}$ is not true in general. I can't follow your reasoning. To answer it, note that if $u \in Ker(ST)$, then we have $S(T(u))=0$, since $S$ is assumed to be $1-1$, we conclude that $T(u)=0$, that is $u \in Ker(T)$. That is $Ker(ST) \subseteq Ket(T)$.

(iii) To prove that it is not $1-1$.

We have $$T\left( u_1+u_3\right)=2v_1$$

$$T\left( u_1-u_3\right)=2v_2$$

Hence $$T\left(\frac32u_1+\frac12u_3\right)=2v_1+v_2=T(u_2)$$

but $\frac32 u_1 + \frac12 u_3 \ne u_2$, hence it is not injective.